# Rewrite URL but have server read old URL

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, dns

Is it possible to use .htaccess to rewrite a url but have the backend i.e. php read the old url. I have a platform I build that allows multiple users. each user gets their own instance via a subdomain.

```
user1.domain.com
user2.domain.com
user3.domain.com
```

I want to allow the users to use their own domain name. i.e.

```
usersDomainName.com points to user1.domain.com
```

This works fine. here is where the issue comes in.

In my system each user has their own config file. the file is named by the subdomain they created i.e. `user1` The system reads the url $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] grabs the subdomain name and looks up the appropriate config file. i.e. if the url is user1.domain.com the system looks up user1.config.php.

how can I use htaccess to mask the url so it reads `usersDomainName.com` but the php reads this `user1.domain.com`

Comment: __You can't do that.__ The fact that `usersDomainName.com` points to `user1.domain.com` at the DNS level just means that the browser has already determined the host is `user1.domain.com` _before it's even reached your web server_, and so it's already too late for you web server do anything about that.

Comment: `usersDomainName.com` successfully points to `user1.domain.com` that is not the issue. the issue is I want the php to recognize to actual path which is `user1.domain.com`

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by "_I want the php to recognize to actual path which is `user1.domain.com`_". That is a domain, not a path. It's quite possible at this point that I have not actually understood the problem you're trying to solve. Perhaps try making your question clearer about what is meant by "`userDomainName.com` points to `user1.domain.com`"?

Comment: my system reads the url to determine which config file to use. in the example above. the instance at user1.domain.com uses user1.config but if  `usersDomainName.com` now points to `user1.domain.com` and the url reads `usersDomainName.com` the system looks for `usersDomainName.config` instead of `user1.config`

Comment: Right, which is why I'm asking you to clarify ___how___ `usersDomainName.com` __points__ to `user1.domain.com` and what exactly is meant by that? For example, did you just ad an `A` record in the DNS for `usersDomainName.com` to the same IP address? The sooner you actually start answering my questions the sooner I can begin helping you. I've already read what you said in your question. It wasn't the information I'm looking for, so please don't bother trying to repeat it in the comments. Thanks.

Comment: sorry, the A record for `usersDomainName.com` points to my IP address.

Comment: Right, so then that's the wrong way to deal with that. You should be using a `CNAME` instead.

Comment: ok, can you explain please?

Comment: No, because this is no longer a programming question. Try asking your DNS/networking question on [ServerFault](http://serverfault.com/about). It has nothing to do with programming.

Comment: I noticed you are involved with ServerFault I have re created my question over there. Since you don't want to answer it here maybe you can answer it there. http://serverfault.com/q/784660/361150

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to my problem came from Julie Pelletier from serverFault.

```
if (!array_key_exists($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'], $clients)) {
    header('Location: http://domain.com/invalidclient');
    exit;
}

$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] = $clients[$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']];
```